# How do I find words in a body of text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing some text processing and I'm interested in finding and scoring paragraphs of text based on frequency of words and/or phrases, using Ruby ideally.

An example of the problem would be: I have "apple", "banana", "fruit salad", and "orange". This list is likely to be several thousand words and/or phrases long.

I have a body of text to search:

> I have a set of apples, and apple computer, and an account on Apple.com but never a fruit salad. Why they never released an Apple Computer that doubled as an orange was beyond me.

This would spit out an array that said:

```
Apple 4
Orange 1
Banana 0
Fruit salad 1
```

Ideally, I'd be able to apply different weights, like the domain "apple.com" gets two points, etc.

Is there a library that is particularly useful for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
text = <<_.downcase
I have a set of apples, and apple computer, and an account on Apple.com. Why they never released an Apple Computer that doubled as an orange was beyond me.
_

["apple", "banana",  "fruit salad", "orange"]
.map{|w| [w, text.scan(/\b#{w}\b/).length]}
# => [
#   ["apple", 3],
#   ["banana", 0],
#   ["fruit salad", 0],
#   ["orange", 1]
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy way to do this is to have a hash of counts, where the `key` is the word, and the `value` is incremented on each word occurrence.

Once you have built your hash then you can easily print out the counts of each words such as `Apple, Orange, Banana`. If case doesn't matter then make sure you convert each word to lower case before using it as the key.

Comment: This would work great, but it doesn't work for branching (apple, apples, applesauce), or phrases.

Comment: That is called "Stemming" where you reduce each word to a common base word. There are definitely perl libraries to do this so I am expecting there are nice text-mining libraries for Ruby too.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/aurelian/ruby-stemmer, seems to be the equivalent to `Linga::Stem` on Perl

Comment: Then you would probably need to include manual rules for things like `http://apple.com` which you would still want to reduce to "apple" (and add two to the iterator instead of one, like you said in the original question)

Comment: Princeton University makes [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu) available which is the basis for a lot of word-analysis tools. There are Ruby gems available to interface with WordNet. A quick Google search, or use `gem search wordnet`, and you should find what you need. Doing word stemming and analysis is only part of the solution when it comes to determine tone in a document. It's not an easy task.

Comment: WordNet looks very promising! Does it support phrases?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your are trying to count the term frequency, try this package https://github.com/reddavis/TF-IDF

Comment: Does this support phrases?

Comment: i think so, take a look at its sample